# Animated Splash Screen in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to implement animated splash screen to the iPhone application. I have seen skype application where same thing is already implemented.

Can anyone has idea how can i implement same thing in my applicatio

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219283/how-to-add-animated-splash-screen-in-our-application)

Comment: Do you mean Alert? Popup? could you be more specific?

Comment: Can u please tell me how u achieve the thing?i want same as Skype splash screen type view..

Answer (score 2):

You can use sequence of images, here is code :

```
for(NSInteger i=1;i<=totalImages;i++){
        NSString *strImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Activity_%d",i];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:strImage ofType:@"png"]];
        [imageArray addObject:image];
    }
    splashImageView.animationImages = imageArray;
    splashImageView.animationDuration = 0.8;
```

and just call startAnimation and endAnimation method of UIImageView.

OR

Its very simple...I had used it in to begin my app with splashView.Hope it vil help you.... In AppDelegate.m:

application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
UIImage* image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"splash.jpg"];
splashView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
[window addSubview:splashView];
[window bringSubviewToFront:splashView];
[self performSelector:@selector(removeSplash) withObject:self afterDelay:2];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

To remove splashView:

```
-(void)removeSplash{

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:window cache:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [splashView removeFromSuperview];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can show a **.gif** image in `webView` and it looks perfect!

Take a new `UIViewController` class named `SplashView` with `XIB` and then add an `UIWebView` with (320.0, 480.0) frame, hidden `statusbar` also.

In `SplashView.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface SplashView : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@end
```

In `SplashView.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"animated" ofType: @"gif"];
   NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
   [self.webView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
   [self.webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"image/gif" textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
}
```

This is about `SplashView` class. Now come to your appdelegate's class.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
     splashView = [[SplashView alloc]initWithNibName:@"SplashView" bundle:nil];
    [self.window addSubview:splashView.view];

    [self performSelector:@selector(changeView) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

-(void)changeView
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    [splashView.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.window setRootViewController:self.viewController];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a UIView & an Imageview into it. Give all your images to ImageView to animate.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
 NSArray *arrImage=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                             nil];

    imgVw.backgroundColor=[UIColor purpleColor];
    imgVw.animationImages=arrImage;
    imgVw.animationDuration=2.5;
    imgVw.animationRepeatCount=1;
    [imgVw startAnimating]; 

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0 target:self selector:@selector(animateNext) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}
```

This will show up you application icon.

After that you will show the controls those would be hidden by default and animate them from bottom to up.

```
-(void)animateNext
{
    lbl.hidden = NO;
    btn.hidden = NO;
    txt1.hidden = NO;
    txt2.hidden = NO;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.9];
    lbl.frame=CGRectMake(lbl.frame.origin.x,lbl.frame.origin.y - 150,lbl.frame.size.width,lbl.frame.size.height);
    imgVw.frame = CGRectMake(imgVw.frame.origin.x, imgVw.frame.origin.y - 150, imgVw.frame.size.width, imgVw.frame.size.height);
    txt1.frame = CGRectMake(txt1.frame.origin.x, txt1.frame.origin.y - 150, txt1.frame.size.width, txt1.frame.size.height);
    txt2.frame = CGRectMake(txt2.frame.origin.x, txt2.frame.origin.y - 150, txt2.frame.size.width, txt2.frame.size.height);
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(btn.frame.origin.x, btn.frame.origin.y - 150, btn.frame.size.width, btn.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];    


}
```

Hope this help...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Appdelegate.h

```
   @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> 
    {
        UIImageView *splashView;
    }

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;

- (void)startupAnimationDone:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

// Make this interesting.
    splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 480)];
    splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
    [self.window addSubview:splashView];
    [self.window bringSubviewToFront:splashView];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:self.window cache:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(startupAnimationDone:finished:context:)];
    splashView.alpha = 0.0;
    splashView.frame = CGRectMake(-60, -85, 440, 635);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    return YES;
}

- (void)startupAnimationDone:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
    [splashView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Hi..its good.. Can you tell me the frame to set for iPhone 5 to Zoom it

Answer (score 1):

you need to start your app with a viewcontroller,with an uiimageview in it..Create a series of .png images to be subjected to the UIImageView [check how to animate array of images in uiimageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249876/images-from-an-array). Further to dismiss it once animation over you would need to implement a protocol that will inform your starting first viewcontroller of your app to dismiss the animation

Answer (score 0):

yes simple in AppDelegate class first defile imageview like bellow..

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder 
{
    UIImageView *splashView;
}
```

and in .m file...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) 
    {
        splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
        splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default"];
        [self.window addSubview:splashView];

        [self performSelector:@selector(loadViewIphone) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
    } 
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

-(void)loadViewIphone 
{
    [splashView removeFromSuperview];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDelegate:self];   
    [animation setType:kCATransitionFade];
    [animation setDuration:0.5];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:
                                  kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [[self.window layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transitionViewAnimation"];
}
```

i hope this help you..

:)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) welcomeScreen
{

 //Welcome Screen
 UIImageView* welcome = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)]autorelease];
 welcome.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"];
 [window addSubview:welcome];
 [window bringSubviewToFront:welcome];

 //Animation Effects (zoom and fade)
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
 [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:window cache:YES];
 [UIView setAnimationDelegate:welcome];
 [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

//set transparency to 0.0
 welcome.alpha = 0.0;

//zoom effect
 welcome.frame = CGRectMake(-60, -60, 440, 600);

 [UIView commitAnimations];


}
```